# PIP: "Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine..."

Tags: python, pip, installation, spyder

Trying to install [spyder](https://pypi.org/project/spyder/) using `pip`:

```
pip install spyder
```

This error pops up:

> Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just solved with:

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
```

Comment: For those using this solution for other packages (in my case, scipy): similar to @vigilantbag2018's answer you may have to prefix the package name (`scipy`) with either `python-` or `python3-` (`sudo apt-get remove python3-scipy`)

Comment: slight variation that worked for me: `sudo apt-get purge ipython*`

Answer (score 54):

You can upgrade ipython without uninstall the old version

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed -U ipython
```

Comment: can this cause some compatibility issues though? when having two different version installed?

Comment: @Färid Alijani, I think it won't. According to pip doc (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/), --ignore-installed overwrites installed packages

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir Spyder
```

For Python 3:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir Spyder
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the solutions listed may work, but this one solved my issue with distutils installed packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-ipython
```

Depending on what type of package it is, you will need to provide the "python-" for python packages.

Edit:
However, if this still does not solve your question, you might want to consider downgrading pip to an earlier version as pip 10 does not allow removal of distutils packages

```
sudo -H pip install pip==9.0.1
sudo pip uninstall ipython
```

Thank you for the comment, as I am looking to improve how I can help people.

Comment: Your "answer" is probably more of a comment as it does not attempt to address pip or distutils correctly. Moreover, you;re suggesting a package removal that is also vague - beware that a lot of stackoverflow users quite naively copy/paste commands to try things out and may end up trying your commands. Please consider improving this answer ..