# cannot install plotly python

Tags: python, pip, plotly

When i type `pip install plotly` i get this message

> Cannot uninstall 'nbformat'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

So, i type `pip uninstall nbformat`, message shows also

> Cannot uninstall 'nbformat'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

How can i install plotly??

Comment: Downgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade "pip<10" `.

Comment: Wow,.... good i solved it!! thank u!! how can i check accepted to your comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933832/7976758