# I want to install python pandas ending pip but it giving me problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

```
Andys-MacBook-Air:~ andyz.$ sudo pip install pandas
Password:

The directory '/Users/andyz./Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/Users/andyz./Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/ad/89670f4017b2459dfb5577775efbc4c6c20eb46728ac6e5b721602493724/pandas-0.23.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (15.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.0MB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/b9/2b485bb32d0b26631f433580d90daad5dea830e6dc5bd18c4f227b1829f7/numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (24.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 24.5MB 932kB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 4.2MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas) (2013.7)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I'm trying to install python pandas through pip but for some ungodly reason when were I try to get pandas it always says that it is numpy and when I check to see if I have pandas in python it will say that panda is not in the existing directory. How would I uninstall numpy. so that I can get pandas

Comment: Your installation of pandas is also trying to install NumPy. Per the error message, numpy was previously installed using distutils. Can you manually remove that numpy installation? See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247#issuecomment-381550610

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP: "Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421287/pip-cannot-uninstall-ipython-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project-and-thus-w)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+uninstall+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall