# Installed Python library but can't Import

Tags: python, module, pip, package

Basically, I've been trying to use the spotipy python library and have tried everything but can't get it to work (Mac OS). When I do:

```
pip install spotipy
```

I get

```
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

And I wasn't sure what I did after that but I did something that seemed to upgrade six to 10.X. But then pip show would say it's in 1.4.1 still. I've been going at this for hours, can someone please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP: "Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421287/pip-cannot-uninstall-ipython-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project-and-thus-w)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+uninstall+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to be using virtualenv. This will allow you to have differing python packages without conflicts. Look this over https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ .

Comment: Thank you so much!!